# Context not pulling in an object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Alright, so I have two models Teacher and Account:

```
public class Teacher : Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TeacherID { get; set; }

    public Guid? AccountID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AccountID { get; set; }

    public Guid? TeacherID { get; set; }

    public String Username { get; set; }

    public String Salt { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public String SaltedPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Secert Question")]
    public Guid SecertQuestionID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    public String SecertAnswer { get; set; }

    public Guid RoleID { get; set; }

    public virtual SecertQuestion Question { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

When I run my GetAll query:

```
public IEnumerable<Account> GetAll()
{
    return context.Accounts;
}
```

My Teacher Object returns null instead of filled in like my Role and SecertQuestion object.

I have fake data that makes sure I have the same GUID for TeacherID and AccountID in the two tables. Also, inside my context creation, I'm using this code to create an optional relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.Teacher)
    .WithOptionalDependent(a => a.Account);
```

Is this correct?

So my question is why is my Teacher object returning null, when I do a GetAll() for my object Account? Is it because my Account Object has a nullable Teacher Object associated with it?

**Update:**

So after analyzing my database, I noticed that with my current mappings, my Account table is creating a new Foreign key called Teacher_TeacherID. How do I go about fixing this while retaining my navigation mappings (virtual objects) in both Teacher and Account.

Comment: Remove the `Teacher.AccountID` and `Account.TeacherID` properties from the classes and test again. They make no sense and EF won't use them in the relationship. Only the two `[Key]` properties matter and must have the same value to associate the account with the teacher.

Comment: @Slauma My Teacher.TeacherID and Account.AccountID will never be the same. I've figured out my problem, but have no idea on how to go about to fixing it. I'll update my question to explain my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach to map the one-to-one relationship would be:

- Remove the `AccountID` property from the `Teacher`. `Teacher` is the principal in your relationship, so it cannot have a foreign key to the dependent `Account`.
- Remove the `TeacherID` property from the `Account` class. You cannot expose this foreign key in the model class. (I don't know why, tbh, but EF doesn't recognize this property as a foreign key by convention and the one-to-one mapping does not have a `HasForeignKey` method available.)

So, you would have then:

```
public class Teacher : Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TeacherID { get; set; }
    //...
    public string Name { get; set; }  // only for the test example below
    //...
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public Guid AccountID { get; set; }
    //...
    public string Name { get; set; }  // only for the test example below
    //...
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Map the foreign key with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.Teacher)
    .WithOptionalDependent(a => a.Account)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("TeacherID"));
```

This will create a nullable foreign key column `TeacherID` in the `Account` table.

If you now have the following rows in the `Teacher` and `Account` table...

[image: One-to-One data]

...you can run this query...

```
var teacher = context.Teachers.First(t => t.Name == "Teacher 1");
var accountName = teacher.Account.Name;
```

...and `accountName` will have the value `"Account 1"` due to successful lazy loading of the `teacher.Account` navigation property.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do a sloppy work around, but this works a lot better. By any chance, is it possible to reorder the column position of TeacherID? I know it's not a big deal, but I like things in order.

Comment: @WesleyPattison: That's a good question. There is no column order option in the mapping with `MapKey`. Maybe the column order in the table is determined by the position of the navigation property `Teacher` in the `Account` class, but I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Navigation properties are not filled by default. Which is a good thing because it prevents inadvertent loading of large quantities of data.

Normally lazy loading will kick in and load the Teacher the first time you access it. But by employing the repository pattern you lose this functionality.

What remains is using Eager loading thus:

```
public IEnumerable<Account> GetAll() 
    { 
        return context.Accounts.Include(account=>account.Teacher); 
    }
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for a more thorough explanation

Comment: But returning an `IEnumerable<T>` from the repo won't disable lazy loading. He also said that lazy loading works for the other two navigation properties. So, there must be a problem with that specific `Account.Teacher` property.

Comment: @Slauma It's possible that lazy loading is disabled for the scenarios that are working.

Comment: @Slauma you're correct. My lazy loading is working correctly for both Role object and SecertQuestion object contained inside my Account object. Does lazy loading get disabled when using a nullable type?

Comment: @WesleyPattison: No, it doesn't.